# GLMM with time-series covariance and binary response variable?

Tags: r, time-series, logistic, multilevel-analysis, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have a binary response variable that was measured at irregular time intervals for a number of individuals. I want to fit a GLMM that accounts for the time-series covariance within individuals.

I know that this is possible for Gaussian response variables by using the `corCAR1` autocorrelation structure in the `nlme` package, but it seems that `nlme` does not fit logistic GLMMs. On the other hand, I can fit a logistic GLMM in the other popular R package for multilevel models, `lme4`, but that package doesn't seem to allow for specifying a time-series covariance structure.

Does anyone know of a way to fit this model in R? I know this model would be useful for many researchers, because I have encountered several researchers working on various problems who also wanted to fit such a model, but couldn't find a way to do it in R, so they resorted to less than ideal models (e.g., simply fitting a logistic GLMM without accounting for the time series).

I would greatly appreciate any advice!!!

Comment: Not a full answer (yet), but I would say your choices are (1) the [INLA package](http://www.r-inla.org/) (off-CRAN); (2) use `MASS::glmmPQL`; (3) there are some hints [here](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/notes/corr_braindump.html) about how to hack `lme4` (not enough to be useful, yet); (4) Steve Walker's [lme4ord](http://stevencarlislewalker.github.io/lme4ord/) package (also alpha-level software ...)